# Grep Syslog firewall logs

Tags: awk, sed, grep, logs

I have a file which contains firewall log like this:

```
Feb             3       0:18:51 17.1.1.1                      id=firewall     sn=qasasdasd "time=""2018-02-03"     22:47:55        "UTC""" fw=111.111.111.111       pri=6    c=2644        m=88    "msg=""Connection"      "Opened"""      app=2   n=2437       src=12.1.1.11:49894:X0       dst=4.2.2.2:53:X1       dstMac=42:16:1b:af:8e:e1        proto=udp/dns   sent=83 "rule=""5"      "(LAN->WAN)"""
```

I need to get an output which should be like this:

```
src=ipaddress:port , dst=ipaddress:port , proto=udp/dns
```

Specifically, for the above input,

```
src=12.1.1.11:49894,dst=4.2.2.2:53,proto=udp/dns
```

I tried

```
cat logfile.txt | awk '{ print $18" "$19" "$21 }'
```

but result seems to different from what I expect.

Comment: Worth showing what you'd expect the output to be, given the example input you've cited.  Oh, and worth adding what you've tried already.

Comment: src=12.1.1.11:49894,dst=4.2.2.2:53,proto=udp/dns is the output i expect

Comment: cat logfile.txt | awk '{ print $18" "$19" "$21 }' is what i was trying but result seems to different from what i expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -o '\(src\|dst\)=[^:]\+:[^:]\+\|proto=[^ ]\+' logfile.txt
src=12.1.1.11:49894
dst=4.2.2.2:53
proto=udp/dns
```

Description:

- `'\(src\|dst\)=` match `src` or `dst` followed by `=`
- `[^:]\+:[^:]\+` one or more non-colon characters, followed by `:`, followed by one or more non-colon characters
- `\|` or
- `proto=[^ ]\+'` match `proto=` followed by one or more non-space characters

We can glue the newlines together with `paste`:

```
$ grep -o '\(src\|dst\)=[^:]\+:[^:]\+\|proto=[^ ]\+' logfile.txt | paste -s -d,
src=12.1.1.11:49894,dst=4.2.2.2:53,proto=udp/dns
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have:

```
awk '{print $18,$19,$21}' OFS=" , " logfile.txt | sed 's|:X[0-1]||g'
```

You don't need `cat` as `awk` already writes to stdout. The command above prints those fields separated by a space which is what the comma does and then it sets the field separator as a comma surrounded by spaces and uses `sed` to remove `:X0` and `:X1`.

The output:

```
src=12.1.1.11:49894 , dst=4.2.2.2:53 , proto=udp/dns
```

Comment: Hi Nasir, but i don't need :x0 or :X1 in the result.

Comment: @user356831 `sed` will trim off the `:X0` and `X:1`

Comment: Thanks You Nasir for the help. Is it also possible to extract the result by greping the word. for example i want the value of "proto" to be printed by just greping the word "proto"