# Grep Match and extract

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file which contains lines as

```
proto=tcp/http  sent=144        rcvd=52 spkt=3 
proto=tcp/https  sent=145        rcvd=52 spkt=3
proto=udp/dns  sent=144        rcvd=52 spkt=3
```

I need to extract the value of proto which is `tcp/http`, `tcp/https`, `udp/dns`.

So far I have tried this `grep -o 'proto=[^/]*/'` but only able to extract the value as `proto=tcp/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can grep output only specified groupings that match?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match)

Comment: This is a job for `sed`, `awk` or `perl`, not `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is related to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/523638/133219), you're going down the wrong track. Rather than trying to piece together bits of scripts that will kinda/sorta do what you want most of the time and needing to get a completely different script every time you need to do anything the slightest bit different, just create 1 script that can parse your input file into an array (`f[]` below) that maps your field names (tags) to their values and then you can do whatever you want with the result, e.g. given this input file from your previous question:

```
$ cat file
Feb             3       0:18:51 17.1.1.1                      id=firewall     sn=qasasdasd "time=""2018-02-03"     22:47:55        "UTC""" fw=111.111.111.111       pri=6    c=2644        m=88    "msg=""Connection"      "Opened"""      app=2   n=2437       src=12.1.1.11:49894:X0       dst=4.2.2.2:53:X1       dstMac=42:16:1b:af:8e:e1        proto=udp/dns   sent=83 "rule=""5"      "(LAN->WAN)"""
```

we can write an awk script that creates an array of the values indexed by their names/tags:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    f["hdDate"] = $1 " " $2
    f["hdTime"] = $3
    f["hdIp"]   = $4
    sub(/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}/,"")

    while ( match($0,/[^[:space:]]+="?/) ) {
        if ( tag != "" ) {
            val = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
            gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|("")?[[:space:]]*$/,"",val)
            f[tag] = val
        }

        tag = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
        gsub(/^"|="?$/,"",tag)

        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    val = $0
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|("")?[[:space:]]*$/,"",val)
    f[tag] = val
}
```

and given that you can do whatever you like with your data just be referencing it by the field names, e.g. using GNU awk for `-e` for ease of mixing a script in a file with a command-line script:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk -e '{for (tag in f) printf "f[%s]=%s\n", tag, f[tag]}' file
f[fw]=111.111.111.111
f[dst]=4.2.2.2:53:X1
f[sn]=qasasdasd
f[hdTime]=0:18:51
f[sent]=83
f[m]=88
f[hdDate]=Feb 3
f[n]=2437
f[app]=2
f[hdIp]=17.1.1.1
f[src]=12.1.1.11:49894:X0
f[c]=2644
f[dstMac]=42:16:1b:af:8e:e1
f[msg]="Connection"      "Opened"
f[rule]="5"      "(LAN->WAN)"
f[proto]=udp/dns
f[id]=firewall
f[time]="2018-02-03"     22:47:55        "UTC"
f[pri]=6

$ awk -f tst.awk -e '{print f["proto"]}' file
udp/dns

$ awk -f tst.awk -e 'f["proto"] ~ /udp/ {print f["sent"], f["src"]}' file
83 12.1.1.11:49894:X0
```

Comment: This is awesome, Thank You soo much :)

Comment: For this sort of job, `perl` may be easier to use.

Comment: @OrangeDog why do you think that? I'd actually like to see the equivalent in perl if you wouldn't mind posting such an answer. Perl definitely won't be easier to use if I don't have it on my box and can't install it, though, which is something I've frequently had to deal with over the years. Awk on the other hand is a mandatory utility and so is always present on UNIX installations, just like sed, grep, sort, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton true, though I have never personally encountered a distribution where perl was not included by default. Complex `awk` and `sed` scripts are usually simpler in `perl` because it's essentially a superset of them, with additional features for common tasks.

Comment: @OrangeDog no-one should ever write a sed script that's more complicated than `s/old/new/g` and sed is not awk so lets set that aside. I utterly disagree that complex awk scripts are simpler in perl. They can be briefer of course but brevity isn't a desirable attribute of software, conciseness is, and it's extremely rare for them to have any real benefit plus they are usually far more difficult to read which is why people post things like https://www.zoitz.com/archives/13 about perl and refer to it as a write-only language, unlike awk. I would still like to see a perl equivalent to this though

Answer (score 13):

With `grep -o`, you will have to match exactly what you want to extract.  Since you don't want to extract the `proto=` string, you should not match it.

An extended regular expression that would match either `tcp` or `udp` followed by a slash and some non-empty alphanumeric string is

```
(tcp|udp)/[[:alnum:]]+
```

Applying this on your data:

```
$ grep -E -o '(tcp|udp)/[[:alnum:]]+' file
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

To make sure that we only do this on lines that start with the string `proto=`:

```
grep '^proto=' file | grep -E -o '(tcp|udp)/[[:alnum:]]+'
```

---

With `sed`, removing everything before the first `=` and after the first blank character:

```
$ sed 's/^[^=]*=//; s/[[:blank:]].*//' file
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

To make sure that we only do this on lines that start with the string `proto=`, you could insert the same pre-processing step with `grep` as above, or you could use

```
sed -n '/^proto=/{ s/^[^=]*=//; s/[[:blank:]].*//; p; }' file
```

Here, we suppress the default output with the `-n` option, and then we trigger the substitutions and an explicit print of the line only if the line matches `^proto=`.

---

With `awk`, using the default field separator, and then splitting the first field on `=` and printing the second bit of it:

```
$ awk '{ split($1, a, "="); print a[2] }' file
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

To make sure that we only do this on lines that start with the string `proto=`, you could insert the same pre-processing step with `grep` as above, or you could use

```
awk '/^proto=/ { split($1, a, "="); print a[2] }' file
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are on GNU grep (for the `-P` option), you could use:

```
$ grep -oP 'proto=\K[^ ]*' file
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

Here we match the `proto=` string, to make sure that we are extracting the correct column, but then we discard it from the output with the `\K` flag.

The above assumes that the columns are space-separated. If tabs are also a valid separator, you would use `\S` to match the non-whitespace characters, so the command would be:

```
grep -oP 'proto=\K\S*' file
```

If you also want to protect against match fields where `proto=` is a substring, such as a `thisisnotaproto=tcp/https`, you can add word boundary with `\b` like so:

```
grep -oP '\bproto=\K\S*' file
```

Comment: You can improve that by writing just `grep -oP 'proto=\K\S+'`. The `proto=tcp/http` may be followed by a tab instead of spaces, and `\S` unlike `[^ ]` will match any non-space character.

Comment: @mosvy: That's a good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Anyway, `-o` is a GNUism as well. `-P` is only supported by GNU `grep` if built with PCRE support (optional at build time).

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$1 ~ "proto" { sub(/proto=/, ""); print $1 }' input
```

`$1 ~ "proto"` will ensure we only take action on lines with `proto` in the first column

`sub(/proto=/, "")` will remove `proto=` from the input

`print $1` prints the remaining column

---

```
$ awk '$1 ~ "proto" { sub(/proto=/, ""); print $1 }' input
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

Answer (score 3):

Code golfing on the `grep` solutions

```
grep -Po "..p/[^ ]+" file
```

or even

```
grep -Po "..p/\S+" file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `cut` command:

```
cut -b 7-15 foo.txt
```

Comment: This will include trailing spaces on the `http` and ``dns`` lines.

Answer (score 2):

Just another `grep` solution:

```
grep -o '[^=/]\+/[^ ]\+' file
```

And a similar one with `sed` printing only the matched captured group:

```
sed -n 's/.*=\([^/]\+\/[^ ]\+\).*/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` approach:

```
$ awk -F'[= ]' '/=(tc|ud)p/{print $2}' file
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

That will set awk's field separator to either `=` or a space. Then, if the line matches a `=`, then either `ud` or `tc` followed by a `p`, print the 2nd field.

Another `sed` approach (not portable to all versions of `sed`, but works with GNU `sed`):

```
$ sed -En 's/^proto=(\S+).*/\1/p' file 
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

The `-n` means "don't print" and the `-E` enables extended regular expressions which give us `\S` for "non-whitespace", `+` for "one or more" and the parentheses for capturing. Finally, the `/p` at the end will make sed print a line only if the operation was successful so if there was a match for the substitution operator.

And, a perl one:

```
$ perl -nle '/^proto=(\S+)/ && print $1' file 
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

The `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line". The `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call (and removes exiting newlines from the input). The script itself will print the longest stretch of non-whitespace characters found after a `proto=`.

Comment: `-E` is getting more and more portable, but `\S` isn't. `[^[:space:]]` is a more portable equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution quite easy:

```
grep -o "[tc,ud]*p\\/.*  "   INPUTFile.txt  |   awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Your `grep` doesn't match anything. `[tc,ud]\*\\/.*` looks for _one_ occurrence of  either `t`, or `c`, or `,` or `u` or `d`, followed by a literal `*` character, then a `p` and a backslash. You probably meant `grep -Eo '(tc|ud)p/.* ' file | awk '{print $1}'`. But then, if you're using awk, you may as well do the whole thing in awk: `awk -F'[= ]' '/(tc|ud)p/{print $2}' file`.

Comment: Someone modified my original, there was an extra Backslash before star, which I just removed Sir.

Comment: Thanks for editing, but I'm afraid that only works by chance. As I explained before, `[tc,ud]p` means "one of `t`, `c`, `,`, `u` or `d` followed by a `p`. So it matches here only because `tcp` has `cp` and `udp` has `dp`. But it would also match `,p` or `tp` etc. Also, now that you have the `*`, it will match `ppp` as well (the `*` means "0 or more" so it will match even when it doesn't match). You don't want a character class (`[ ]`), what you want is a group: `(tc|ud)` (use with the `-E` flag of `grep`). Also, the `.*` makes it match the entire line.

Comment: @terdon: (1) No, actually it won’t match `ppp`.  Of course you’re right that it will match `,p` or `tp` — or `uucp`, `ttp`, `cutp`, `ductp` or `d,up`.

Comment: @G-Man It will also match `ppp`, try `echo ppp | grep -o "[tc,ud]*p"`. And no, pointing out errors in my (or anyone else's) comments is absolutely fine! But the general issue you raised should be discussed on meta. Or, at least, by leaving comments under _my_ answer, so we don't bombard poor mkzia with notifications about stuff not related to this answer. I [moved the comments to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94676/discussion-on-answer-by-mkzia-grep-match-and-extract), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1}' filename|awk -F "=" '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file| cut -f1 -d' '| cut -f2 -d'='
tcp/http
tcp/https
udp/dns
```

cut options:

- `-f` - field
- `-d` - delimeter